# localhost sent an invalid response for my vue project

Tags: vue.js, npm, localhost

・Build vue.js project

```
$ npm run dev
```

・get response

```
> vue-test@0.0.0 dev
> vite

Port 5173 is in use, trying another one...

  VITE v4.5.0  ready in 218 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5174/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
(node:2968) Warning: An error event has already been emitted on the socket. Please use the destroy method on the socket while handling a 'clientError' event.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

[npm run dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeJdC.jpg)

・It can't display in my browser, here's the screenshot

[localhost sent an invalid response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjLWo.jpg)

[ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjLWo.jpg)

[Remove vueCLI and reinstall - didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk0NW.jpg)

[clientError → Socket destroy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qgx7.jpg)